# tapestry4 method called when page load

Tags: java, tapestry

pagevalidate() method will be called each time the page is refresh and i did some action on the page. I looking for a method that will only be call first time the page is loaded and for subsequent time the page is refresh/do some actions, the method will not be called.  any such method in tapestry 4?

Comment: You do seem to be a fan of (unnecessarily) complicated frameworks :)

Comment: hehe=) it used to be a famous framework few years back

Comment: Yes, and it's a famous framework now, but for all the wrong reasons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try setting a flag in the session object and wrap the code that you only want called the first time in an if-block that is entered by checking that flag.